# Save my Gesture using Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium-modules

I am developing **android** and **ios** application using **Titanium appcelerator**, Now i need to **draw or paint** in my Activity and want to **save that as a image**.

-I have found this module [***Ti.paint module link***](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paint/mobile/android)

- The above module works good , i can able to paint with this, But i **can't** able to **save** my **gesture**

I been searching and i couldn't find the way to save my painting..

Can anyone enlighten me guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, to save my gesture paint..

Code is:

```
var filename = "savedPainting1.jpg";
var sigImg = paintView.toImage().media;
var img = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory, filename);
img.write(sigImg);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var sigImg = paintView.toImage().media;
```

and save to your file system.

[link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149853/tipaint-save-image-issue)